# Centre the drawable in the button

Tags: android

I have a button with a text and drawable in it. It is as shown below -

[image]

I want the width of the button to be unaltered but the text `HI` to be removed and centre the drawable which is an arrow mark.

My code is -

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/HIButton"
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/xml_HI_button"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/arrow_mark"
            android:text="HI"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:textSize="24sp" />
```

Comment: remove the `android:text="HI"` and set `android:background="@drawable/arrow_mark"`

Comment: try to use ImageButton

Comment: Actually i changed `android:text=""` or delete it and its working perfect.  Also you can use ImageButton with `android:scaleType="center"`

Comment: @YasinKaçmaz I did what you suggested...Removed the line android:text but still no effect. The arrow mark is still placed in the left side of the button

Comment: @Mark023 if you want only icon why you dont use `ImageButton` , did you tried with `ImageButton` ?

Comment: @YasinKaçmaz I just want to avoid use of image button to save resources and size...

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `text` and `textSize` attributes to remove text and add `foreground` with `foregroundGravity` to achieve centering.

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/HIButton"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/xml_HI_button"
        android:foreground="@drawable/arrow_mark"
        android:foregroundGravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" />
```